# Spring RestTemplate gives timeout when used in Spring Boot console app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I'm using the following block of code to call an external application:

```
String accessToken = "...";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(UPDATE_BODY, headers);
String url = "...<url>...";
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

When I use the block of code in a Spring Boot web application, it works fine. However, when running the same block in a Spring boot console application, I'm getting the error below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.example.webapp.CallApplication.main(CallApplication.java:43) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "<...url...>": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:748) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:583) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.example.webapp.delegate.CreateIdentityRecordDelegate.execute(CreateIdentityRecordDelegate.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.example.webapp.CallApplication.run(CallApplication.java:48) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Any help or clue is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that the `url` is correct?

Comment: I replaced the real url by this string. The url works ok when used from a web app.

Comment: Is your firewall blocking the application?

Comment: Why would it block it only for command line apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the proxy needs to be configured for command line and it does not need to be configured for web applications. Don't know where it gets the configuration from.